# How many rows for your star design?

Tags: c

I want to be able to print a flag like this when the user enters any number for the input:

[image: Flag]

Current Code:

```
printf("How many rows for your star design?\n");
scanf("%d", &num_rows);

printf("How many stars on the first row?\n");
scanf("%d", &num_symbols);

/*** Add your loops here  ***/

for(i=0;i<num_rows;i++)
{
    if(i%2 == 0)
    {
        for(j=num_symbols; i>=1; i--)
            printf(" *");
        printf("\n");

    }
    else if(i%2 == 1)
    {
        for(j=num_symbols; i>=0; i--)
            printf("* ");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, but the "else if" can just be an "else" as the i%2==1 will always be true.

Comment: I get the compiler warning `variable 'j' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]`. Take a look at the second and third `for` loop.

Comment: `for(j=num_symbols; i>=1; i--)` --> `for(j=num_symbols; j>=1; j--)` this is a "typo error" question.

Comment: `i%2 == 0` <==> `i%2 == 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num_rows, num_symbols, i, j;
    printf("How many rows for your star design?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num_rows);
    printf("How many stars on the first row?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num_symbols);
    for(i=0;i<num_rows;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
            for(j=num_symbols;j>0;j--)
                printf("* ");
        else
            for(j=num_symbols;j>1;j--)
                printf(" *");
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there was a little detail that I was missing. It was the i variables, they were supposed to be j variables.